# Display current time- hour and minute

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display the current time on the display (hours and minutes). How can I do it most efficiently in terms of performance. I'm Using this technique for solve my question. Please help me

[image: Check My Image]

```
   time: function (data: any) {
        debugger

        console.log(`Now`);

        // formatDate(date: any, format: string): string { return moment.utc(date.toString()).local().format(format); }

        return {
         field: '<input  class="form-control" type="time" value="13:30"/>',
          // field: '<input class="form-control" type="datetime" #RequiredByDate name="RequiredByDate" [value]="formatDate(hitchRequest.requiredByDate)">',
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by three column.I changed your inner grid like this

```
<Grid  Padding="10" RowSpacing="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="ID Type" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblIdType" Text="NIC"  FontSize="Small" TextColor="black"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="ID Number" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblIdNumber" Text="65125457V"  FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label   x:Name="lblIdNumberNew" Text="ID Number(New)" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblOldNic" Text="15665544" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="Title" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblTitle" Text="MS" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="First name" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblFname" Text="TEST"   FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="Last name" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblLname" Text="TEST1" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Gender" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblGender" Text="F" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblDobSelector" Text="Date of birth" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblDob" Text="5/11/1900" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="Language" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlylblLang" Text="ENG"  FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label  Text="Nationality" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblNationality" Text="LKA" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Postal Code" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="genrealsectionforreadonlyPcode" Text="DEFAULT" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I got something like this.
[image: Screenshot of result]